# 'module' object is not callable in server runtime but ok in django console

Tags: python, django, django-models

Weirdly, it has worked before and now it doesn't:

getting the following error:

```
Exception Value:    
'module' object is not callable
Exception Location: C:\work\Portman\core\models\pmo_review_task.py in save, line 38
```

if I change "from core.models import sc_review_task" to "from core.models import *" the error message will change to "global name sc_review_task is not defined."

if I run django admin and do:
from core.models import sc_review_task
a = sc_review_task()

it all looks ok - no error messages.

please help me figure this out, I'm loosing hair :)

pmo_review_task (line 38 is "newtask = sc_review_task()"):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from core.models import sc_review_task

class pmo_review_task(models.Model):
    project_phase_to_review = models.ForeignKey('project_phase')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    is_closed = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=False)
    review_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    review_comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    reviewed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    is_review_result_ok = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)
    scheduled_sc = models.ForeignKey('sc_event', null=True, blank=True)
    review_goal = models.ForeignKey('phases')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.project_phase_to_review.project.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if self.is_closed and self.is_review_result_ok and self.scheduled_sc is None:
            raise models.ImproperlyConfigured

        if self.is_closed and self.is_review_result_ok is False:
            self.project_phase_to_review.is_finished = False
            self.project_phase_to_review.is_approved_for_sc = False
            self.project_phase_to_review.save()

        if self.is_closed and self.is_review_result_ok and self.scheduled_sc:
            if self.scheduled_sc.has_taken_place is True:
                raise Exception("Cannot assign a task to a SC event that has taken place")
            #update reviewed project to indicate it has been saved
            self.project_phase_to_review.is_approved_for_sc = True
            self.project_phase_to_review.save()
            #create sc_review_talk
            newtask = sc_review_task()
            newtask.project_phase_to_review = self.project_phase_to_review
            newtask.sc_event_to_review_at = self.scheduled_sc
            newtask.review_goal = self.review_goal
            newtask.is_closed = False
            newtask.save()
            #call real save operation
        super(pmo_review_task,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'core'
```

sc_review_task:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from core.models import project_phase

class sc_review_task(models.Model):
    sc_event_to_review_at = models.ForeignKey('sc_event', null=False)
    project_phase_to_review = models.ForeignKey('project_phase', null=False)
    review_goal = models.ForeignKey('phases',related_name="target_review_goal")
    is_closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    review_decision_phase = models.ForeignKey('phases', null=True, blank=True,related_name="sc_decided_phase")
    review_decision_comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.project_phase_to_review.project

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(sc_review_task,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.is_closed and self.project_phase_to_review.phase == self.review_decision_phase:
            self.project_phase_to_review.is_approved_for_sc = False
            self.project_phase_to_review.is_finished = False
            self.project_phase_to_review.is_closed = False
            self.project_phase_to_review.save()
        elif self.is_closed:
            self.project_phase_to_review.is_closed = True
            self.project_phase_to_review.save()
            new_phase = project_phase()
            new_phase.project = self.project_phase_to_review.project
            new_phase.phase = self.review_decision_phase
            new_phase.save()

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'core'
```

each of the classes sits in its own file within /models/ and here is the **init**.py:

```
from divisions import divisions
from django.db import models
from groups import groups
from phases import phases
from pmo_review_task import pmo_review_task
from priorities import priorities
from progress_indicator import progress_indicator
from project import project
from project_imported_from_excel import project_imported_from_excel
from project_phase import project_phase
from project_phase_history import project_phase_history
from project_status_submit_form import project_status_submit_form
from roles import roles
from sc_event import sc_event
from sc_review_task import sc_review_task
from milestone import milestone
from milestone import milestone_history


__all__ = ['divisions',
           'groups',
           'phases',
           'pmo_review_task',
           'priorities',
           'progress_indicator',
           'project',
           'project_imported_from_excel',
           'project_phase',
           'project_phase_history',
           'project_status_submit_form',
           'roles',
           'sc_event',
           'sc_review_task',
           'milestone',
           'milestone_history']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your namespaces...

in pmo_review_task (line 38 is "newtask = sc_review_task()") it should be `newtask=sc_review_task.sc_review_task()`

Comment: why should it be a sc_review_task.sc_review_task when it gets imported as sc_review_task from sc_review_task in __init__.py for models? same way it works for pmo_review_task when it gets created.

Comment: You import "sc_review_task" module. So that will be his name. _Inside_ it you have a class "sc_review_task()". So it's address will be `sc_review_task.sc_review_task()` (as in `module_name.class_name.method_name()`)

Comment: By the way - if you insist on using `newtask = sc_review_task()`, then your import should look like `from sc_review_task import sc_review_task` (but beware - this should be done for all classes/methods inside sc_review_task module separately)

Comment: yeh fair enough but when I do from core.models import * it should have imported properly then since the '__init__.py' imports them as classes from modules. all weird all weird, thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the error is that you're trying to execute `sc_review_task` instead of `sc_review_task.sc_review_task`.

To prevent this kind of mistakes, I think you should name your modules using lowercase letters and your classes using uppercase letters, that is, the module should be `sc_review_task` and the class `ScReviewTask`.

For more inforation, please have a look at [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Package and Module Names
>
> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names.  Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability.  Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is discouraged.
>
> ...
>
> Class Names
>
> Almost without exception, class names use the CapWords convention. Classes for internal use have a leading underscore in addition.